# Cannot get TeamCity to authenticate to GitHub with Default Private Key

Tags: git, github, ssh, teamcity

I'm trying to get TeamCity to build my private GitHub repository. I'm able to successfully get my VCS root to pass the connection test when I explicitly set the path to the key file; however, despite lots of Googling, I can't get it to work when I use the 'Default Private Key' option. I get `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail`.

Both my TeamCity server and build agent are running as a user called (*gasp*) `teamcity`, and the contents of `C:\users\teamcity\.ssh\` include both a `config` and a key file, where the config is pointing to the key file. My config contains:

```
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.key
```

I've tried a variety of different path styles, both Windows and Unix style, but none seem to work.

Again, it works fine if I use the `private key` setting and explicitly set the path to the key file, but not when I use the `default private key`, which I apparently need for my build agent to work.

Comment: I was able to work around this by using username/password authentication, but I'd much rather use a key.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope =( still using username / password.

Comment: @FMM I am thinking it has to do with the passphrase. Have you tried creating an SSH key pair without a passphrase?

Comment: @FMM you have exactly my problem. Could you ever solve it using the default private key?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest solution for me was this:

1. Upload your (OpenSSH) key under your Pipeline's project settings "SSH Keys" (as seen below):

   [image: Pipeline - Project settings (ssh)]

   > *Look at resource links for OpenSSH info (why/how)*
2. And then in VCS root settings, Update "Authentication Settings" as seen below:

   [image]

   > - *note*: the username is; "**git**" (see 3rd resource)
3. Make sure your "Fetch URL" look something like "git@bitbucket.org:ProjectName/RepositoryName.git" - (*Note*: Github equivalent is required here)
4. Add your new key (see 1st resource)

**Resources:**

- [Here's a link that helped me get to the solution (see section for Putty keygen)](http://laurentkempe.com/2012/08/24/TeamCity-and-Gitlab-working-together-with-SSH-Keys/)
- [TeamCity Docs regarding SSH Keys](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/SSH+Keys+Management)
- [Username should be "git"](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206933505-Help-Configuring-git-cvs-root-with-ssh)

Answer (score 2):

Git looks for the .ssh folder by forming a path with %HOMEDRIVE%/%HOMEPATH%. I've found that even though the %USERPROFILE% environment variable is set correctly these are not set. If %HOMEDRIVE%  is empty %SYSTEMDRIVE% will be used instead so by default it will look for .ssh folder in c:\ (or whatever your system drive is).

You can check the environment variables an agent has via the agent parameters tab when selecting an agent and what a build is using via the parameters tab of the build.

#### Solution 1

create .ssh folder in c:

#### Solution 2

Set environment variables for %HOMEDRIVE% & %HOMEPATH% to match where your userprofile is

#### Solution 3

git also can use %HOME% environment variable this is the full path i.e. equal %USERPROFILE%

Answer (score 0):

`default private key` also disabled when one use `http://...` url and not `git@...`