# TeamCity Git VCS SSH connection with Custom Private Key throws JschException: Auth fail

Tags: git, ssh, teamcity, private-key, gitolite

I can't seem to get TeamCity to read my Git (Gitolite) repository... I get an exception:

```
List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```

What I've tried: (I use PuTTY to export them to OpenSSH format)

1. Use personal working(!!) private/public keys
2. Generate private/public key with PuTTy for teamcity user
3. Generate private/public key from Git Bash with ssh-keygen for teamcity user

All private keys have passphrase and I use the Custom Private Key setting to configure it.
My fetch url looks like this: git:ssh://user@host/path/to/repository

No matter what I try... I always get the same exception:

```
jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.OperationContext.wrapException(OperationContext.java:165)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:339)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getCurrentState(GitVcsSupport.java:128)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.TestConnectionCommand.checkFetchConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:95)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.TestConnectionCommand.testConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:68)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.testConnection(GitVcsSupport.java:252)
    at jetbrains.vcs.api.services.impl.TestConnectionServiceProvider$1.testConnection(TestConnectionServiceProvider.java:1)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.TestConnectionCommand.runTestConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:3)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.TestConnectionCommand.doTestConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:30)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.EditVcsRootsController.doPost(EditVcsRootsController.java:176)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseFormXmlController$1.handleRequest(BaseFormXmlController.java:53)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.AjaxRequestProcessor.processRequest(AjaxRequestProcessor.java:45)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseFormXmlController.doHandle(BaseFormXmlController.java:51)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseController.handleRequestInternal(BaseController.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.TeamCityDispatcherServlet.service(TeamCityDispatcherServlet.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.DependencyParametersCalculationContextFilter.doFilter(DependencyParametersCalculationContextFilter.java:4)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.DisableSessionIdFromUrlFilter.doFilter(DisableSessionIdFromUrlFilter.java:4)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.DiagnosticFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.ResponseFragmentFilter.doFilter(ResponseFragmentFilter.java:16)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git:ssh://user@host/path/to/repository: Auth fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:356)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:335)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
    ... 57 more
```

I do get other exceptions when the wrong path or passphrase are defined

SourceTree, git-cola, PuTTY, etc. are working fine...

I'm accustomed to use TeamCity with Stash/BitBucket and a username/password, which always seemed to work, but Gitolite won't let me use a username/password. :(

Comment: I posted an answer for [Cannot get TeamCity to authenticate to GitHub with Default Private Key](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29456482/3933585 ) that might answer this as well.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem when trying use my Unfuddle git as a VCS Root. To actually fix it, I found the link [here](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206933505-Help-Configuring-git-cvs-root-with-ssh) which specified changing the Username in the VCS Root Authentication Settings to `git`.

Comment: You can also leave it blank, and it will use the fetch url's username, which is typically "git" - "git@github.com:myawesomeorg/myawesomerepo.git"

Comment: YES!!
Just add your repository URL,

Username : `git` <username it takes as git@gitlab.com> so `git` is a username here.

Password : <Your GIT password>

Answer (score 0):

In my case github key was incorrect. Key placed at **~/.ssh/<your_git_key>** on Teamcity Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add public key in github,the exception"List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail" may occur.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your local git command works this way from shell

```
git clone user@githost:/home/git/my_project
```

which it would after doing a `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id-rsa user@githost`

then use the ssh protocol method in TeamCity and not the git protocol. i.e this url.

```
ssh://user@githost:/home/git/my_project
```